# Following SQL Query, help needed to return records out of ForEach

Tags: sql, powershell, foreach, export-to-csv

```
[string] $Server= 'NERD\PAULSDB'
[string] $Database = "myPhotos"

$ShootDate= Get-Content -Path W:\W-SQL\PS\ShootDate.txt 

ForEach ($S_Date in $ShootDate){
$SqlQuery=@"
SELECT * FROM Target.U_PhotoYears where StrmydateTaken= '$S_Date'
"@
$resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $SqlQuery 

function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';Integrated Security=true;"
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
    $Datatable.Load($Reader)
    $Connection.Close()  
    return $Datatable
}

$data=$(foreach($a in $resultsDataTable)
        {
         $a.P_Filename+$a.myYearTaken
        }
    )
 $data 
}
```

Text file has a distinct list of dates from all photo shoots. The first ForEach appears to be retrieving data ok. Then the Powershell script queries the myPhotos db based on values from text file. The query return the correct records for a given date.

However I cant get the records out of the second foreach to Export-Csv.
Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use bulkcopy for send your datas into temporary table. its really better for performance (you do only 3 actions on database and not X actions => X dates into you files)

try this (not tested)

```
$Connection=$null
$dttemporary=$null
$sqlBulkCopy=$null
$FinalData=$null
$Command=$null
$Reader=$null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" #for stop script on first error

try
{

#create datatable for send data
$dttemporary = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
[void]$dttemporary.Columns.Add("mydate")

#add data to datatable
Get-Content -Path W:\W-SQL\PS\ShootDate.txt  | %{
$NewRow=$dttemporary.NewRow()
$NewRow["mydate"]=$_
$dttemporary.Rows.Add($NewRow)
}


#Create connexion
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';Integrated Security=true;"

#create bulkcopy structure for send all data
$sqlBulkCopy = New-Object (“Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy”) -ArgumentList $Connection
$sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = “#TmpTable”

#Create datatable for final data 
$FinalData = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

#create command
$Command = $Connection.CreateCommand()

$Connection.Open()

#create temporary table (exsit while connexion stay open)
$Command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #TmpTable(mydate varchar(30) NOT NULL)"
$Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

#send data to temporary command with bulkcopy
$sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer($dttemporary)

#query for get your final datas
$Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Target.U_PhotoYears f1 inner join #TmpTable f2 on f1.StrmydateTaken=f2.mydate"
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
$FinalData.Load($Reader)

$Connection.Close()

#loop on data for traitment
$FinalData | %{
$_["P_Filename"].ToString() + $_["StrmydateTaken"].ToString()
}



}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}

finally
{
    if ($Connection) 
    {
        $Connection.Close()
        $Connection.Dispose()
    }

    if ($dttemporary) {$dttemporary.Dispose()}
    if ($sqlBulkCopy) {$sqlBulkCopy.Dispose()}
    if ($FinalData) {$FinalData.Dispose()}
    if ($Command) {$Command.Dispose()}
    if ($Reader) {$Reader.Dispose()}

}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that has really helped. Thank you

Comment: Although I can export the records, problem now is the script uses the last date in the ShootDate.txt file and returns all records. I have 1,000+ dates in the file so that is why my initial thought was a ForEach. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont understand your problem. If you want use the last date of your file, add only the last date into the datatable $dttemporary

Comment: for take the last element of you file use Get-Content yourpathfile -tail 1